# How to align / valign css-rotated span within its parent div

Tags: css, css-transforms

How do I get the "feedback" span bang in the middle of the purple div?

http://jsfiddle.net/XcWHr/

I have tried a few variations on these themes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform-origin?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2F-moz-transform-origin

Bit can't quite hit the nail on the head...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this situation it would be easier to rotate the purple div instead of the feedback span.  That way you could reason about the horizontal and vertical centering separately from the rotation.  Is this feasible?  I've updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XcWHr/2/

I set your "feedback" span to be centered in the regular fashion and reversed the width and height of the container:

```
.feedbackTab 
{
    height: 42px; 
    width: 156px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 42px;
}
```

Then I set the "feedback" span to `display: inline-block` to respect the centering rules on its container.  Finally, I placed your `.rotate` class on the container instead of the "feedback" span.